# Populating a configuration file

Tags: perl

I am reading a file `standard.p.config` whose lines have indentations.

The file contains the fields that must be filled from the servers.

After retrieving the values, the programs create an output file, with field values populated for the fields.

But the output file does not get populated with the correct values when the standard file has indentations.

I require these indentations in the output file for further processing.

The `standard.p.config` file

```
DESCRIPTION: Config for lddfvt testcases
AUTO_PROVISIONED:
  HMC_HMC1_NAME:
  HMC_HMC1_PASS:abc123
  MANAGEDMC_MANAGEDMC_NAME:p9zzd-fsp
  LPAR_LPAR1_NAME:
  LPAR_LPAR1_PASSWD:passw0rd
  LPAR_LPAR2_NAME:
  LPAR_LPAR2_PASSWD:passw0rd
 os_env:AIX
 nodecount:2
 default_host:host1
 default_con_mode:telnet
 host1:$LPAR_LPAR1_NAME
 host1_login:root
 host1_password:$LPAR_LPAR1_PASSWD
 host1_test_slot:
 host1_test_slot1:
 host1_test_slot2:
 exact_match_mcast_counter:32
 host2:$LPAR_LPAR2_NAME
 host2_login:root
 host2_password:$LPAR_LPAR2_PASSWD
 host2_pp_slot:
 host2_pp_slot1:
 back_to_back_setup:
 switch1:
 switch1_vendor:BNT
 switch1_login:admin
 switch1_password:admin
 host1_switch1_port1:
 host1_switch1_port2:
 host2_switch1_port1:
 host1_test_ip1:
 host2_test_ip1:
 host1_test_ip2:
 host2_test_ip2:
 ip_netmask:255.255.255.0
 mcast_ip1:225.1.2.6
 mcast_ip2:225.1.2.7
 unicast_test_mac:0x00:11:22:22:33:33
 vlan_tag_id:
 vlan_tag_id2:
 long_run_duration:1
 eid_run_duration:1
 FIRING_NODE:$LPAR_LPAR3_NAME
SCRIPTS: ~
```

Until `LPAR_LPAR2_PASSWD` it has two indentations, and after that one indentation per line.

This the code

```perl
open FILE1, "/home/jenkins/config/standard.p.config" or die;

my %hash;

while ( my $line = <FILE1> ) {
    chomp( $line );

    ( my $word1, my $word2 ) = split /:/, $line;    #/
    my $config_filename = "/home/jenkins/config/$filename";

    # write a switch to match your variable and fill in place of word2;
    # if paattn matches then $word2=$var;

    # $hash{$word1} = $word2;

    switch ( $word1 ) {
        case "LPAR_LPAR1_NAME"     { $word2 = "$host1" }
        case "LPAR_LPAR2_NAME"     { $word2 = "$host2" }
        case "host1_test_slot"     { $word2 = "$host1_test_slot" }
        case "host1_test_slot1"    { $word2 = "$host1_test_slot1" }
        case "host1_test_slot2"    { $word2 = "$host1_test_slot2" }
        case "host2_pp_slot"       { $word2 = "$host2_pp_slot" }
        case "host2_pp_slot1"      { $word2 = "$host2_pp_slot1" }
        case "switch1"             { $word2 = "$Switch_IP" }
        case "host1_switch1_port1" { $word2 = "$host1_switch1_port1" }
        case "host1_switch1_port2" { $word2 = "$host1_switch1_port2" }
        case "host2_switch1_port1" { $word2 = "$host2_switch1_port1" }
        case "host1_test_ip1"      { $word2 = "$host1_test_ip1" }
        case "host1_test_ip2"      { $word2 = "$host1_test_ip2" }
        case "host2_test_ip1"      { $word2 = "$host2_test_ip1" }
        case "host2_test_ip2"      { $word2 = "$host2_test_ip2" }
        case "vlan_tag_id"         { $word2 = "$vlan_tag_id" }
        case "vlan_tag_id2"        { $word2 = "$vlan_tag_id2" }
        case "back_to_back_setup"  { $word2 = "$back_to_back_setup" }
        case "vlan_tag_id2"        { $word2 = "$vlan_tag_id2" }
        case "back_to_back_setup"  { $word2 = "$back_to_back_setup" }
        case "HMC_HMC1_NAME"       { $word2 = "$HMC_HMC1_NAME" }
        case "unicast_test_mac"    { $word2 = "0x00:11:22:22:33:33" }
    }

    $hash{$word1} = $word2;

    open( my $fh, '>', $config_filename ) or die "Could not open file '$config_filename' $!";
    print $fh Dump \%hash;
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: Please include the text instead of an image, and please do show your code.

Comment: Thank you for the code, but there is still an image of `standard.p.config`.  Can you please include plain text instead, that can be copied?

Comment: `switch` and `case` aren't standard in Perl. Where do they come from?

Comment: This is a part of an old code that i am trying to use, but execution is not giving me desired results.

Comment: This code looks like it should just use a `hash` and be done with it.

Comment: *"This is a part of an old code that i am trying to use"* Maybe, but you have also hacked it before showing the result without really knowing what you are doing. At no point does your code write anything to an output file apart from the (presumably diagnostic) `Data::Dumper` output. This isn't rocket science: you clearly don't have any idea what you're doing so you should employ someone who does, or spend the time to become familiar with the language. *Stack Overflow* will not give you step-by-step instructions to hack your system into life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few direct errors and they are addressed first. A few comments are at the end.

**The `case` statement**

When you use `case` value under quotes (`"..."`) it is tested for equality to the `switch` value, and in this case it is tested for string equality with `eq`.

But all of your `$word1` have leading spaces, preserved by `split /:/`. This satisfies your requirement to keep them, but none of the `case` values have leading space so the tests fail.

You want to use a regex match instead

```
switch ($word1) {
    case /\bLPAR_LPAR1_NAME\b/ { $word2 = $host1 }
    ...
}
```

which means `$word1 =~ m/\bLPAR_LPAR1_NAME\b/` and will match, according to your file.

The *word boundary*  anchor `\b` is needed to distinguish strings containing each other, like `host` and `host1` and `host1_test_slot`.  Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for a comment. See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for starters.

It seems that you are using the [Switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Switch.html) module.  Please note that it is a source filter with very complex behavior. I suggest choosing other constructs.  Below I use a simple cascading `if-elsif` instead, as the most direct match for `switch` functionality.

**The output file**

is opened and written each time through the loop, each time overwriting the one written in the previous iteration. Write the output file after the loop completes.  Thanks to [thanos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2418001/thanos) for a comment.

**Data structure chosen to assemble results**

The configuration file clearly relies on the order of lines. In the output the line `AUTO_PROVISIONED:` must be followed by the same lines that follow it in the input.  However, using a hash to assemble tag-value pairs denies this since the hash in Perl is inherently unordered.  You could use modules keeping order for a hash but it is far simpler to use an array to collect output lines.

Another question in this regard is of what exactly you need to do. Supply only the missing values? There are other ways to do the processing but since the goal is not stated in the question I can only raise the point. I merely replace the `switch` with its most direct alternative.

You "dump" diagnostic output to disk without stating what module is used and I'd rather not guess what provides the `Dump` function (it's not [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html)). Instead, why not write a config file?

The variables providing values are undefined so I include only a few cases using string literals.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = 'standard.p.config';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!"; 

my $outfile = $file . '.new';  

my @out_lines;

while (my $line = <$fh>) { 
    chomp($line);

    (my $word1, my $word2) = split /:/, $line;    #/ preserves indentation

    $_ = $word1;  # for cleaner regex below

    if    (/\bLPAR_LPAR1_NAME\b/)     { $word2 = 'host1' } # $host1 not given..
    elsif (/\bLPAR_LPAR2_NAME\b/)     { $word2 = 'host' }
    elsif (/\bhost1_test_slot\b/)     { $word2 = 'host1_test_slot' }
    ...    
    elsif (/\bunicast_test_mac\b/)    { $word2 = '0x00:11:22:22:33:33' }

    push @out_lines, "$word1: $word2";
}
close $fh;

open my $fh_out, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";

say $fh_out $_  for @out_lines;

close $fh_out;
```

Consider more descriptive variable names instead of `$wordN` (say, `tag` and `value`).  Please replace strings (`'host'`) with your variables (`$host`), once they are defined.

Comments

- Always have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top of the program
- There is no reason to double-quote a variable (`$word2 = "$host1"`); it is evaluated for the assignment anyway. It can only be misleading and even lead to subtle problems
- Lexical filehandles (`my $fh`) in [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) are plain better than globs (`FILE1`)
- When using `die` print the actual error, at least as `die $!`.
  See [Error variables in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables)

Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for comments.

Comment: To add a minor comment in the analytical answer ot zdim. Do not open, write and close your file in your while loop, do it after. You have your hash defined correctly outside of the loop then simply finish your loop and dump the data as you do after! Currently you wright again and again on your file after every single line.

Comment: @Thanos: I don't think overwriting the debug file is a major consideration, it just underlines that the OP hasn't a clue what they're doing. There is no code shown here that influences the problematic output.

Comment: *"I suggest to switch to using simple `if-elsif` instead"* @zdim: Or even just a *hash*, or [`String::Interpolate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Interpolate)? Honestly, I'm surprised at you: you know much better than this.

Comment: @Thanos  Thank you, edited (along with a considerable expansion)

Comment: @Borodin 1. Thank you for the criticism, edited (rewritten, rather).  2. Please refrain from qualifications like "_cheap and irresponsible_".  I thought that I did address the main point (honestly missing a couple of others) and I don't know what being (more) "responsible" would imply.  I don't know what "_cheap_" even means, except that it sure seems offensive.  You mean like a cheap shot for points?  Seriously?  On this question?  (You should know me better than that, btw.)

Comment: @Borodin As for other approaches -- sure, there are many, but _I chose to suggest the cascading `if` specifically_.  What does that choice (of mine) have to do with "knowing better than this"?  Btw, a hash wouldn't help much since they need to deal with each particular tag.  And while that module seems very interesting I don't see how it relates to this question.

Comment: @Borodin Btw, I did address their concern that indentation be kept (by commenting that `split /:/` preserved it). While the original post did need more work, thank you.

Comment: @ray Re-written the answer.  It prints the correct output in my tests, judged by what I can infer from the question and with literal strings instead of (undefined) variables, but please let me know how it works for you.

Comment: @ray Great :)   Let me know if things/questions pop up